# Maven does not take account a variable category defined in the pom

Tags: maven, testing, categories

I have two tests into my Maven test project.  I define two categories as interfaces that I use in the following ways: (@Category(HighTest.class) for 'testLR' method and @Category(MediumTest.class) for'testFD' method. I have also defineD these two interfaces in my project as

```
 package com.groups.project;

 public interface MediumTest {

}
```

I want to run the test methods matching a single category. When running these tests following a specific category (from the command line) by the use of mvn -Dtest.category=MediumTest test or mvn -Dtest.category=HighTest test, all test methods are being run (testLR and testFD) while I'd only like the test that matches the category that i specify to run.
I have even changed MediumTest in MediumTest.class or "MediumTest" but it does not change anything , all tests are always run
It looks to me as if my variable test.category within pom is not readable by jvm.
See here my Maven test project and POM. Thanks for helping me out!

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org    
/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org     
/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.open-projet</groupId>
<artifactId>open-android</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>open-android</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <properties>
 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>
 <build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.13</version>
     <configuration>
<groups>${test.category}</groups>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.8</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>2.37.0</version>
   </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.39.0</version>
  </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Test Code

```
package com.groups.project;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import com.google.common.io.Files;


/**
 * @author selenese
 * 
 */

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class getConnectFD {

private String quoiqui;
private String ou;  
private WebDriver driver = null;


/**
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */

@Parameters
public static Collection data(){
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{{"restaurant", "newyork"},});
}

public getConnectFD(String quoiqui, String ou){
    super();
    this.quoiqui = quoiqui;
    this.ou = ou;   
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    driver = (WebDriver) SingleDriver.getInstance();    
}

/**
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    //driver.quit();
}


@Test
@Category(HighTest.class)
public void testLR() throws InterruptedException {

    String item;

    // Step 1
    driver.get("http://m.opentour.fr/sprint3-p");
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    // Find the text input element by its name
    WebElement quiquoiou = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='activity']"));
    quiquoiou.click();
    WebElement input1 = null;
    input1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='globalActivity']")); 
    //  Enter something to search for
     input1.sendKeys(quoiqui);       
     input1.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
       AssertEquals("Trouver",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).
  getText());
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
     Thread.sleep(3000);

}

@Test
@Category(MediumTest.class)
public void testFD() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("test");
}


public @interface HighTest {}

public @interface MediumTest {}
```

}

Comment: Have given the full package of the group class? Or only the name of the class?

Comment: yes, Athough given the full package, all test methods run

Comment: I tried very hard and finally was able to find out my error. I want to share it with you. Indeed, I have just cleared the interfaces defined into my test class to keep these one I defined in their own files. All is fine now.